# django django_authopenid.openid_store error in apache

Tags: python, django, apache, openid

I am getting the following error on my website:

```
Error importing openid store django_authopenid.openid_store: "No ElementTree library found. You may need to install one. Tried importing ['lxml.etree', 'xml.etree.cElementTree', 'xml.etree.ElementTree', 'cElementTree', 'elementtree.ElementTree']"
```

I have commented all the django openid code and all the imports, still its giving the error.

When I run the project in django development server by doing:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It works fine. But in apache its giving the the above error. I have even installed all the required packages and checked by running import and the module name, in the python shell on the server, its importing fine, still its giving the error.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

this one is fixed, there was an url in the urls.py file and i commented that and now everything is working fine.